# Count $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to count this limit:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n!}{n^n}$ ?
I have no idea how to even start. I will be glad for any tips or help.

Comment: Hint: $${n!\over n^n}=\underbrace{{n\over n}\cdot{n-1\over n}\cdot{n-2\over n}\cdots  {2\over n}}_{\le 1}\cdot{1\over n}\le {1\over n}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you allowed to use? The simplest approach is Stirling expansion of $n!=(\frac{n}{e})^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}(1+o(1))$. The limit is of course $0$.

Answer (score 5):

David Mitra's suggestion is the simplest one. Just notice that

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac n n \frac{n-1} n \frac {n-2}n ...\frac 1 n < \frac 1 n$$

The inequality happenning because every term on the product is smaller or equal to 1. But you know the limit for $\frac 1 n$ (in most books, it's one of the most basic concepts), and $\frac {n!} n$ is always bigger or equal to zero, so you have your answer.

Comment: Sorry, this was done before David editted his comment to LaTeX.

Comment: Stirling in this case is using a bazooka to get an ant.

Comment: Knee-jerk reaction...